# Bookdown: Fix extra space before Chinese string inside R code chunk

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, bookdown

When Chinese string inside R code chunk, the compiled PDF will get a redundancy space before the string, how to avoid this extra space? Please refer the minimum case in [github - bookdown-chinese](https://github.com/sulaxd/bookdown-chinese) .

[image: example]

Comment: Come on! I have been frustrated so many times by those who vote to close questions without looking at the tags. The OP has given a perfect minimal reproducible example, and have any of you looked at it at all? How many of you actually use bookdown? And how many of you write Chinese? If you are not an expert in these areas, please give beginners a chance to defend themselves before you put questions on hold!

Comment: @YihuiXie voted to reopen, but it seems virtually none closed post could be flipped.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks for your support. And your bookdown.

Comment: @georgexsh Thank you improved my question description.

Comment: Here is the solution to your problem: https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/commit/c70ef766b117f3 I cannot post it as an answer since they have put this question on hold, but the solution is simple enough.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks a lot. It's work!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This issue was caused by the LaTeX package **xeCJK**. By default, it adds spaces between Chinese and non-Chinese characters, except in `verbatim` environments. In your case, the code was not actually in a `verbatim` environment, so you have to let **xeCJK** know that it should not add spaces automatically.

The solution is to add this line to your LaTeX preamble (the `Highlighting` environment was defined by Pandoc when converting Markdown to LaTeX to syntax highlight code, and it is based on the **fancyvrb** package):

```
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\},formatcom=\xeCJKVerbAddon}
```

For R Markdown documents, this line can be save in a .tex file, e.g., `preamble.tex`, and included via the `includes` option, e.g.,

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
```

See [this Github issue](https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/331#issuecomment-353653567) for the full technical background.